# Sequentially comparing groupby values conditionally

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

Given a dataframe

```
data = [['Bob','25'],['Alice','46'],['Alice','47'],['Charlie','19'],
['Charlie','19'],['Charlie','19'],['Doug','23'],['Doug','35'],['Doug','35.5']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Customer','Sequence'])
```

Calculate the following:

1. First `Sequence` in each group is assigned a `GroupID` of 1.
2. Compare first `Sequence` to subsequent `Sequence` values in each group.
3. If difference is greater than .5, increment `GroupID`.
4. If `GroupID` was incremented, instead of comparing subsequent values to the first, use the current `Sequence`.

In the desired results table below...

- Bob only has 1 record so the `GroupID` is 1.
- Alice has 2 records and the difference between the two `Sequence` values (46 & 47) is greater than .5 so the `GroupID` is incremented.
- Charlie's `Sequence` values are all the same, so all records get `GroupID` 1.
- For Doug, the difference between the first two `Sequence` values (23 & 35) is greater than .5, so the `GroupID` for the second `Sequence` becomes 2. Now, since the `GroupID` was incremented, I want to compare the next value of 35.5 to 35, not 23, which means the last two rows share the same `GroupID`.

**Desired results:**

| CustomerID | Sequence | GroupID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 25 | 1 |
| Alice | 46 | 1 |
| Alice | 47 | 2 |
| Charlie | 19 | 1 |
| Charlie | 19 | 1 |
| Charlie | 19 | 1 |
| Doug | 23 | 1 |
| Doug | 35 | 2 |
| Doug | 35.5 | 2 |

**My implementation:**

```
# generate unique ID based on each customers Sequence
df['EventID'] = df.groupby('Customer')[
                'Sequence'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]) + 1

# impute first Sequence for each customer for comparison
df['FirstSeq'] = np.where(
    df['EventID'] == 1, df['Sequence'], np.nan
    )

# groupby and fill first Sequence forward
df['FirstSeq'] = df.groupby('Customer')[
    'FirstSeq'].transform(lambda v: v.ffill())

# get difference of first Sequence and all others
df['FirstSeqDiff'] = abs(df['FirstSeq'] - df['Sequence'])
    
# create unique GroupID based on Sequence difference from first Sequence
df["GroupID"] = np.cumsum(df.FirstSeqDiff > 0.5) + 1
```

The above works for cases like Bob, Alice and Charlie but not Doug because it is always comparing to the first `Sequence`. How can I modify the code to change the compared `Sequence` value if the `GroupID` is incremented?

**EDIT:**
The dataframe will always be sorted by Customer and Sequence. I guess a better way to explain my goal is to assign a unique ID to all `Sequence` values whose difference are .5 or less, grouping by Customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has errors -> add  `df = df.astype({'Customer':str,'Sequence':np.float64})` would fix it. But still you cannot get what you want with this design. Try to define your own lambda function `myfunc`, which solves your problem directly:

```
data = [['Bob','25'],['Alice','46'],['Alice','47'],['Charlie','19'],
['Charlie','19'],['Charlie','19'],['Doug','23'],['Doug','35'],['Doug','35.5']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Customer','Sequence'])
df = df.astype({'Customer':str,'Sequence':np.float64})

def myfunc(series):
    ret = []
    series = series.sort_values().values
    for i,val in enumerate(series):
        if i==0:
            ret.append(1)
        else:
            ret.append(ret[-1]+(series[i]-series[i-1]>0.5))
    return ret

df['EventID'] = df.groupby('Customer')[
                'Sequence'].transform(lambda x: myfunc(x))
print (df)
```

Happy coding my friend.

Comment: Thank you very much!